# How to create globally available functions in Perl?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to create global functions available across all namespaces like perl built-in functions?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: @choroba I'm writing a DSL in perl and I need to have some global functions available in all project packages without the need to import them package by package.

Comment: You can always declare subroutines in the `main::` package and call them as `main::frobnicate()`. But depending on subroutines defined in `main` is a code smell, as it reduces the reusability of the modules.

Comment: My purpose is to have the `frobnicate` symbol globally available but I guess it's a little bit tricky :-(

Comment: I would recommend using [`use`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) to import the common functions.

Comment: See also [CORE](https://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html)

Comment: Håkon Hægland the [CORE](https://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html) module allow to override or alias only perl [built-in functions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) not to define a new one :-(

Comment: Name your functions [`ENV`,`INC`,`ARGV`,`ARGVOUT`,`SIG`,`STDIN`,`STDOUT`,`STDERR`, or `_`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#The-Syntax-of-Variable-Names)

Comment: While injecting symbols into code that doesn't expect it is a very bad idea, consider [Import::Base](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import::Base) and even further [App::MyPerl](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::MyPerl) as mechanisms to easily introduce a set of imports into all code files in a project (but critically, *not* all of the CPAN modules it uses).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, "function" is the name given to Perl's named list operators, named unary operators and named nullary operators. They are visible everywhere because they are operators, just like `,`, `&&` and `+`. Subs aren't operators.

Second of all, you ask how to create a global sub, but all subs are already global (visible from everywhere) in Perl! You simply need to quality the name of the sub with the package if it's not in the current package. For example, `Foo::mysub()` will call `my_sub` found in package `Foo` from anywhere.

But maybe you want to be able to say `mysub()` instead of `Foo::mysub()` from everywhere, and that's a very bad idea. It violates core principles of good programming. The number of types of problems it can cause are too numerous to list.

There is a middle ground. A better solution is to create a sub that can be imported into the namespaces you want. For example, say you had the module

```
package Foo;
use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( my_sub );
our %TAGS = ( ALL => \@EXPORT_OK );
sub my_sub { ... }
1;
```

Then, you can use

```
use Foo qw( my_sub );
```

to load the module (if it hasn't already been loaded) and create `my_sub` in the current package. This allows it to call the sub as `my_sub()` from the package into which it was imported.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing simple that would allow one to somehow "register" user's subs with the interpreter, or some such, so that you could run them as builtins in any part of the program.

One way to get the behavior you ask for is to directly write to symbol tables of loaded modules. This has to be done after the modules have been loaded, and after subs that you add to those modules have been defined. I use `INIT` block in the example below.

Note that this has a number of weaknesses and just in general the idea itself is suspect to me, akin to extending the interpreter. Altogether I'd much rather write a module with all such subs and use standard approaches for good program design to have that module loaded where it needs to go.

Having said that, here is a basic demo

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd pp);

use TestMod qw(modsub);

sub t_main { say "In t_main(), from ", __PACKAGE__ }

modsub("Calling from main::");

INIT {
    no strict 'refs';
    foreach my $pkg (qw(TestMod)) {
        *{ $pkg . '::' . 'sub_from_main' } = \&t_main;
    }
    dd \%TestMod::;  
}
```

This copies the reference to `t_main` from the current package (`main::`) into the symbol table of `$pkg`, under the name of `sub_from_main`, which can then be used with that name in that package.

For simplicity the name of the module is hardcoded, but you can use `%INC` instead, and whatever other clues you have, to figure out what loaded modules' stashes to add to.

The benefactor (or the victim?) module `TestMod.pm`

```
package TestMod;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(modsub);

sub modsub {
    say "In module ", __PACKAGE__, ", args: @_";
    say "Call a sub pushed into this namespace: ";
    sub_from_main();
}

1;
```

The name of the added sub can be passed to modules as they're loaded, instead of being hardcoded, in which case you need to write their [import](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html) sub instead of borrowing the `Exporter`'s one.

There are also modules that allow one to add keywords, but that's no light alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be no, but you can impliment most of the behaivior that you want by using the symbol table `*main::main::` to define a subroutine in all the namespaces.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my $xx = *main::main::;

package A;

sub test {
   printf "A::%s\n", &the_global;
}

package B;

sub the_global
{
   "This is B::the_global";
}

sub test {
   printf "B::%s\n", &the_global;
}

package main;

my $global_sub = sub { "The Global thing" };
for my $NS (keys %$xx) {
   if ($NS =~ /^[A-Z]::$/) {
      my $x = $NS . 'the_global';
      if (defined &$x) {
          printf "Skipping &%s\n", $x;
      } else {
          printf "Adding &%s\n", $x;
          no strict 'refs';
          *$x = $global_sub;
      }
   }
}

A::test;
```

This will not work on packages that are not referenced at all before the for loop above is run.  But this would only happen if a `require`, `use` or `package` was `eval`'d after the code started running.

This is also still a compiler issue!  You either need to refer to the global function as `the_global()` or `&the_global` if you are (as you should be) using `use strict`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late response and thank you all for yours detailed answers and explanations.

Well.. I understood the right answer is: IT'S NOT POSSIBLE!

I'm mantaining a Perl framework used by some customers, and that framework exports some specialized subs (logging, event handling, controllers for hardware devices, domain specific subs and so). That's why I tried to figure out how to prevent the developers from importing my subs in all their packages.